# sudo gem install vmc doesn't install vmc

Tags: cloud-foundry

I'm trying to follow instructions to install cloud foundry vmc.

http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/tools/vmc/installing-vmc.html#installing-vmc-main-steps

I do the following:

gem update -> seems to work

ruby -v -> 1.9.3p194

sudo gem install vmc -> seems to complete successfully

vmc target -> -bash: vmc: command not found

vmc target api.cloudfoundry.com -> -bash: vmc: command not found

why does it seem that vmc installs successfully but isn't executable?

Comment: which OS type are you on? can you downgrade your ruby version to 1.9.2 as it is supported by CF?

Comment: If you are on ubuntu, could you please check whether the directory where the gem was installed is in the PATH? If not "export PATH=$PATH:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin" will get you out of it. The detailed doc is at http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/frameworks/ruby/installing-ruby.html#ubuntu

Comment: As William asks, which OS is this? on the Mac, running that gem install command certainly causes a Ruby wrapper script for vmc to be symlinked (I use rvm, so I have that at /Users/andyp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/vmc)

Comment: Mountain Lion. 10.8.2. Installing RVM turned out to be a colossal pain in the neck because it wanted all sorts of dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I ran into this problem because the ruby I was using was not the default version that rvm was setup to use. You can figure this out by first running

rvm info

If it doesn't say ruby-1.9.3-p194 (or whatever your default is), then you can run

rvm use ruby-1.9.3

Once I did this, my vmc commands starting working.

My thought on this is that when we install vmc using gem install, it installs to the default ruby's gems regardless of whether that ruby is what you are currently setup to use.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a good idea to totally get rid of RVM and have a try on the stock ruby version shipped by OS X 10.8 because "sudo gem install" probably is out of RVM's perspective. Or simply remove sudo and see whether gem install vmc works.